# A solvable group is characteristically simple if and only if is abelian elementary

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ a finite group. I know that

> $G$ is solvable $\iff$ every principal factor is abelian elementary

I already showed that if $G$ is a abelian elementary group then $G$ is characteristically simple (and $G$ has structure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector-space).

Suppose then $G$ is solvable and characteristically simple. I tried to use the result quoted above for to show that $G$ is abelian elementary, but I only got it in the case where $G$ was simple. How to do in the characteristically simple case?

Any help is so appreciate.

Comment: Note that the commutant is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristically_simple_group): In particular, a finite solvable group is characteristically simple if and only if it is an elementary abelian group. It is proved in the reference.

Comment: @kabenyuk yes, and so $G$ is abelian. How to conclude that $G$ is elementary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an outline argument.

1. $G$ finite and solvable implies $G$ has a nontrivial normal $p$-subgroup for some prime $p$, and the largest such subgroup $O_p(G)$ is characteristic in $G$, so $G=O_p(G)$ is a $p$-group.
2. Finite $p$-groups have nontrivial centre $Z(G)$ which is characteristic, so $Z(G)=G$ and $G$ is abelian.
3. Now $ \{ g : g \in G, g^p=1 \}$ is a characteristic subgroup and hence equal to $G$, so $G$ is elementary abelian.

Comment: Sorry, but how to show that $G$ has a nontrivial normal $p$-subgroup if $G$ is finite and solvable?

Comment: Alternative outline: 1.) By solvability $[G,G] \lneq G$, so $[G,G] = 1$. 2.) Sylows of an abelian group are characteristic, so $G$ is an abelian $p$-group. 3.) As in the answer.

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira You said that you knew that $G$ finite solvable implies that its principal factors (usually called chief factors) are elementary abelian. So $G$ has an elementary abelian normal subgroup.

Comment: Oh yes, because $G$ has a minimal normal subgroup. Thank you